# Microsoft Access/Count words

Tags: vba, ms-access

How I can count words in a Access column?
Example I have 33 words "Rec" and 20 with "NoRec" and I want the number to display in two text-boxes, one for Rec and one for NoRec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you need VBA to do this, you can make use of the `TOTALS` Query to get the desired result you want.

```
SELECT 
    Sum(IIF(yourColumnName = "Rec", 1, 0)) As TotalRec,
    Sum(IIF(yourColumnName = "NoRec", 1, 0)) As TotalNonRec
FROM 
    YourTableName
```

Answer (score 1):

An Access Column is a column of an Access Table. So you SELECT all rows of that table, get the column you want into a string and count the number of words in that string. Assuming the column is `myColumn` and the table is `myTable`:

```
Private Sub Test()
Dim dbs As Database
Dim rst1 As Recordset
Dim s As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    With dbs
        ' Select all records
        Set rst1 = .OpenRecordset("SELECT myColumn FROM myTable;", dbOpenDynaset)
        While (Not rst1.EOF)
            s = rst1.Fields("myColumn")
            ' now analyse s
            '
            rst1.MoveNext
        Wend
        rst1.Close
    End With
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Sub
```